# Invalid use of group HAVING

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I am trying to write a query to select the highest value of a selection.

```
SELECT especialidad,COUNT(*)
    FROM medicos    
        GROUP BY especialidad
        HAVING COUNT(*)=(SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
            FROM medicos
                ORDER BY nombre,especialidad);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the second `order by` is irrelevant due to the `max(count(*))` you can simply do

```
SELECT especialidad, COUNT(*)
FROM medicos    
GROUP BY especialidad
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `order by desc and limit 1`

```
SELECT especialidad,COUNT(*) as total
FROM medicos    
GROUP BY especialidad
order by total desc limit 1
```